# Configuring the EPSON L455 Scanner on Ubuntu 18.04.2

Tags: 18.04, scanner, epson

I recently adopted Ubuntu Linux 18.04.2 LTS as the OS for my development environment. However I need to keep using administrative activities on the same machine and I am having difficulty using the scanner of my Epson L455 All-In-One.

I can print normally and have installed the EPSON driver [Image Scan 3.55.0 (64 bit)](http://support.epson.net/linux/en/imagescanv3.php) to configure the scanner. In Image Scan I can even preview the scan, however, when I put it to scan: it creates the file in the folder I chose with the name I defined; the multifunctional informs that it is scanning, but at the end of the process the file disappears from the folder and I am not finding the file anywhere else.

Has anyone gone through this and have some guidance to help me solve the problem?

Comment: Do you have write permissions to the selected location?

Comment: Yes, I chose to generate file on my desktop.

Comment: Try another folder. Desktop shouldn't be used for that anyway.

Comment: I chose the documents folder and it happened the same way. I also tried to change the file type to .jpeg but also the same thing happened. : (

Comment: Can you save other files in your user area? Like in the Documents or Pictures folders?

Comment: Yes I have other files in these same folders.

Comment: That was not the question. The question was can you create/save new files **now** in those locations? We're trying to determine if there are permissions issues.

Comment: Yes I can save new files in these folders.